# Why are two vertical scrollbars showing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, overflow

I did something like this to initially hide the body scrollbar, and then show it when a link is clicked:

```
$('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
$('#site').click(function(e) {
    $('#wrapper').remove();
    $('body').css('overflow', 'scroll');
    return false;
});
```

At first, it does hide the scrollbar and just shows a scrollbar for the overlay (absolutely positioned div (#wrapper)) but when I click on the link (#site) to show the scrollbar again (and remove the overlay), it now shows two scrollbars: one is working, the other is disabled.

#### HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
   --- some content ----
   <a href="" id="site"></a>
</div>

<div>
   --- rest of the website ---
</div>
```

#### CSS:

```
#wrapper {  
    background-color: #CCC;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 99999; 
    height: 800px;
}
```

What has gone wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure entirely what you're trying to do though it does seem like there's an easier route to hiding & showing the scroll. Please can you provide the html and css. or put it in http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I posted now the HTML and CSS. Bascially I'm trying to have a mask over our existing page. This mask contains a promotion of some sort which they will see first when they land on the page. They can click on a link inside this mask to view the actual page if they're not interested in the promo.

I don't want to show the scroll bars at first because they will see the actual page if they scroll down past the height of this mask layer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Found a solution to my problem. I just needed to add:

```
$('html').css('overflow', 'hidden');
```

Comment: Used this in css: html { overflow-x: hidden !important; }

Comment: Thanks, it turns out I had two overflow properties being set and that was causing my issue. Your solution made me look.

Answer (score 9):

You also can use this, in case something from a theme or style is causing the second bar

```
html {
  overflow-x: initial !important;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

In my case I tried

```
$('html').css('overflow', 'hidden');
```

which was removing the two sidebar but I was unable to scroll down to footer.

I used:

```
$('html').css('overflow-x', 'initial');
```

Which is working perfectly, shows only one scrollbar vertically and it is scrollable to all content at the bottom

Answer (score 2):

None of the solutions above worked for me. I tried adding `overflow-y: hidden;` in html and body. Finally, it worked when I added it to what I identified to be a problematic `<div>`.  I found the problem by using Inspect Elements: I highlighted the additional scrollbar by using the "select" tool, and it showed me to which element it belonged - in my case it was a `<div>` called `.main`. Reference the screenshot below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

By two scrollbars do you mean a vertical and horizontal scrollbar? If it is, use overflow:auto instead of scroll

http://jsfiddle.net/DmqbU/2/

This will effectively only show scrollbar when needed (if horizontal content is wider than width or vertical content is taller than height)

Comment: Sorry, I mean 2 vertical scrollbars. I already edited my title.

Answer (score 1):

This solved the problem for me:

```
body{overflow-y:auto}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` to manage horisontal and vertical scrollbars. Just set `overflow-x: none;` to stop showing horisontal bar.

Answer (score 0):

add these lines to your `style.css` code:

```css
html {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0%;
    padding:0%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```